# python className not defined NameError

Tags: python, class, nameerror

I have a class which i need to instantiate in order to call a method that it contains. When I access it from another class it works fine but when i run from terminal it says :

```
File "myClass.py", line 5, in <module>
  class MyClass:
File "myClass.py", line 23, in ToDict
  td=MyClass()
NameError: name 'MyClass' is not defined
```

Pasting the code:

```
class MyClass:
    def convert(self, fl):
        xpD = {}
        # process some stuff
        return xpD

    if __name__ == "__main__":
        source = sys.argv[1]
        td = MyClass()
        needed_stuff = td.convert(source)
        print(needed_stuff)
```

Comment: Presumably you imported the module with `import toDict`. In that case, the class is available as `toDict.ToDict`, not just `ToDict`. If you insist on the name `ToDict`, import it with `from toDict import ToDict`.

Comment: This helped me... Thanks a lot.. I spent hrs figuring out why it is not recognizing..

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The problem is that your `if __name__ == "__main__"` block is inside of your class definition. This will cause an error, as the code within the `if` will be run as part of the class being created, before the class been bound to a name.

Here's a simpler example of this error:

```
class Foo(object):
    foo = Foo() # raises NameError because the name Foo isn't bound yet
```

If you format your code like this (that is, with the `if` unindented at the top level), it should work correctly:

```
class MyClass:
    def convert(self, fl):
        xpD = {}
        # process some stuff
        return xpD

if __name__ == "__main__":
    source = sys.argv[1]
    td = MyClass()
    needed_stuff = td.convert(source)
    print(needed_stuff)
```